# How do you change your Airport or Ethernet MAC address in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook, mac-address, airport, ifconfig

I have a MacBook Pro and would like to set a custom MAC address for either my Airport WiFi card, or Ethernet port. In older versions of Mac OS X, you could do it like this:

```
$ sudo ifconfig en0 ether 00:11:22:33:44:55      // Ethernet
$ sudo ifconfig en1 lladdr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF     // Airport
```

For it to work on Airport, you'd have to power it on (e.g. `$ sudo ifconfig en1 up`), ensure it's not connected to any wireless network, and execute the command. I'm aware such a change won't propagate across reboots.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Mac OS X 10.6.6 anymore. Apple appears to have removed the functionality (the command fails silently). Does anyone have any idea how to do it? Thanks for any help you can offer! :)

---

**UPDATE:** Automated Python script: https://github.com/dave-gallagher/MacSpoofer

Comment: `networksetup` only allows read-access to the MAC address using `-getmacaddress`.

Comment: I had te opportunity to check this suggestion on a 10.6.6 and now on a 10.6.7 system. I could not use the newly set mac address for connecting to any wireless routers with either of the two versions. When trying to connect after the modification of the mac the connection simply times out. So I would not call it a working solution.

Comment: Checkout the github link I added to the question. It's a script that'll work with 10.6.7. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://osxdaily.com/2008/01/17/how-to-spoof-your-mac-address-in-mac-os-x/

there are extended directions at the bottom of this page using the "ln" command. it will work on 10.6.6 after you wait for "connection timeout" error when joining a fake ssid.

Answer (score -1):

You can install Virtualbox and run a LINUX machine in there. In LINUX you can easily configure a different MAC address for each connection you configure.